# How can I detect longtap gesture on MapBox SDK for IOS?

Tags: ios, mapbox

How can i detect longtap gesture on MapBox SDK for IOS?

I try below code.
but mapLongTap are never called.

```
-(void)mapInit
{
    RMMBTilesSource *offlineSource = [[RMMBTilesSource alloc] initWithTileSetResource:@"tokyo5" ofType:@"mbtiles"];
    mapView = [[RMMapView alloc] initWithFrame:_mapBaseView.bounds andTilesource:offlineSource];
    mapView.zoom = 0;
    mapView.delegate = self;
    mapView.missingTilesDepth = 5;
    mapView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    mapView.adjustTilesForRetinaDisplay = YES;    
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(mapLongTap:)];
    [longPressGesture setMinimumPressDuration:1.0];

//  [_mapBaseView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];
    [mapView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];

    [self.mapBaseView addSubview:mapView]; 
}

-(void)mapLongTap:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    NSLog(@"LongTap");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`RMMapView` already has a long press gesture recognizer. See `-[RMMapViewDelegate longPressOnMap:at:]`.

Comment: @incanus - the problem is this doesn't actually give you access to the gesture, nor does it seem to allow for another longpress gesture to work simultaniously. Any suggestions how to circumvent this?